# Missing Field In Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-9

I have a report with a field that does not display. In the Report Explorer, the field displays with a red arrow as seen in the image linked to below. The report pulls from a stored procedure. I do not see the required fields in the crystal reports document, but the fields displays in the software for which the report was made.

https://www.mediafire.com/?fxyuif1q3346h6t

Comment: There could be any number of reasons for a field (although your image suggests we're talking about an entire subreport) to not display in a report. More detail and investigation is going to be required before we'll be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

The red arrow is pointing to a subreport. Right click that sub in the report explorer and select edit subreport. That's where the fields you are referring to are coming from.